# Problem in converting null or empty string to decimal

Tags: apex, rest

I've implemented a REST HTTP method for lead creation. There is a Number field XYZ(16,2) field. When I tried to insert with a null value it is giving an error like invalid decimal. Please help me.

```
private static Lead getLeadMapping(Lead_API_Wrapper.LeadCreationRequestWrappper objRequest, String ownID){
    Decimal MRR = 0;
    string EstimatedMRR = objRequest.EstimatedMRR;
    if(String.isNotBlank(EstimatedMRR) || EstimatedMRR != null){
        MRR = Decimal.valueOf(EstimatedMRR);
    }
    String street = objRequest.AddressLine1;
    street = String.isNotBlank(street) && String.isNotEmpty(street) ? + street + ', ' + objRequest.AddressLine2 : objRequest.AddressLine2;
    return new Lead(FirstName = objRequest.FirstName, LastName =objRequest.LastName, 
                    Phone = objRequest.PhoneNumber, Email = objRequest.PrimaryEmail, OwnerId = ownID,
                    Company = objRequest.CompanyName, Street = street, City = objRequest.City, 
                    State = objRequest.State, PostalCode = objRequest.ZIPCode, Country = objRequest.Country,
                    EstimatedMRR__c = MRR, EstimatedCloseDate__c = objRequest.EstimatedCloseDate);

}
```

In wrapper class LeadCreationRequestWrappper:

```
global String EstimatedMRR;
```

I am not adding complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely on this line:

```
if(String.isNotBlank(EstimatedMRR) || EstimatedMRR != null){
```

You are using a logical OR (`||`) between the two conditions rather than an AND (`&&`). As a result, if `EstimatedMRR` is an empty string it will still pass the `EstimatedMRR != null` condition.

Try changing that line to:

```
if(EstimatedMRR != null && String.isNotBlank(EstimatedMRR)) {
```

Better yet, [`String.isNotBlank()` will handle null](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isNotBlank). So all you need is:

```
if(String.isNotBlank(EstimatedMRR)) {
    MRR = Decimal.valueOf(EstimatedMRR);
}
```